# how much data can charts js handle

Tags: javascript, html, charts

For my application, I am making a get request of thousands of data points.
When I use charts js to display the data, it takes a long time to render, and I experience lag. I also noticed that the x-axis labels for each data point don't appear properly, so they had to be omitted

I like the sleek design and ui of the graphs, but cannot get it to work well for my use case. Is charts js not meant to be used with large data sets? Is there another library like charts js that can handle large data sets? While also being free?

Comment: "how much data can charts js handle"? It depends. On what? Lots of factors: System, browser, data, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to handle big data you should use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo)
it easy can handle some million data without a big delay

Comment: This seems like a good option, but I'm concerned that the charts will leave some watermark until I buy the license

Comment: Hmm jeah that's possible I used it in the company where I do an intership at the moment and we had a license but even with a watermark it's very good

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/)... It is made with WebGL. It can render

- 1 million data points in ~80 ms in line chart
- 10 million data points in ~800 ms

that is for static data. Those I got from my PC (AMD Ryzen, NVidia GTX1060)

But for scrolling streaming data, the performance is yet more impressive. Dozens of millions of points, with some configurations with Firefox browser, over 100 million points.

There is a [chart performance tester application](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-performance/)

[image]

*I work with the team making this chart...*

Answer (score 5):

Another option to consider is [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). It is free as a branded version, but renders large amounts of data quickly while still maintaining flexibility in customization. If you are looking for a sleek design and UI, ZingChart allows the user to change just about every size, shape, and color to match your taste.

Full disclosure, I am on the ZingChart team. However, we developed a [speed test tool](http://www.zingchart.com/demos/zingchart-vs/) that I think you will find helpful in testing your number of data points, regardless of which library you end up selecting. Note that some of these libraries will use up all your browser memory, so proceed with caution in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, Charts js seems to be unable to handle large data sets. The best alternative I've found is https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs . Also you could try http://canvasjs.com/ although it is comercial.

Comment: I ended up using highcharts, since they offer non-commercial use for free to students, and its really nice to use. There is a way to remove the watermark too.